# How to have a "no image found" icon if the image used in the function returns an error?

Tags: php

In my application I use timthumb for resizing images. Those images are not controlled by me because I get them from RSS feeds. Sometimes the image are not shown in my page. When I examine the entire link with the timthumb I get this

> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(http://www.domain.com/image.jpg)
>   [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /timthumb.php on line 193 Unable to
>   open image : http://www.domain.com/image.jpg

So, I am looking for a way to know when an image returns an error, so that I will not display it on page ( the red X icon).

From my RSS feeds, I use regex to get the first image

```
if (thumb[0]) { show the image using timthumb } 

else { show a no-image icon }
```

but the example above falls into the "show the image using timthumb".

This is a paste from my code
http://codepad.org/7aFXE8ZY

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a function which fetch headers for the given url using curl and check for the HTTP status code and for the `image/*` content type.

If your url refer to an image the following function will return `true`, otherwise it returns `false`.

Notice the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);` line which tells curl to fetch only the headers for the given page and not the whole content. In this way you can save bandwidth when checking for image existence.

```
<?php
function image_exist($url, $check_mime_type = true) {    
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if (!preg_match('/^HTTP\/1.1 200 OK/i', $result)) {
        // status != 200, handle redirects, not found, forbidden and so on
        return false;
    }
    if ($check_mime_type && !preg_match('/^Content-Type:\\s+image\/.*$/im', $result)) {
        // mime != image/*
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

$url = 'http://static.php.net/www.php.net/images/php.gif';
var_dump(image_exist($url)); // return true since it's an image
$bogus_url = 'http://www.google.com/foobar';
var_dump(image_exist($bogus_url)); // return false since page doesn't exist
$text_url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
var_dump(image_exist($text_url)); // return false since page exists but it's a text page
```

By using this code you could avoid the `@` error suppression operator, which should not be used and fetch the actual image only when it exists.

`@` is bad since it will suppress even fatal error, so your script can die with a blank page and you won't know why because it will set error_reporting to 0 and the restore it to its previous value, see the warning [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).

Furthermore it slows down your code as reported in [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php#102543) and following.

Comment: @mtopia This function just checks that the remote image exists. You still need a thumbnail library, you should use this code before it to avoid the `imagecreatefromjpeg` 404 error. My performance notice is just a comparison with the `@` operator.

Comment: Note that he wants do load the image. While this solution is excellent for just the existence test, if you're loading the image, you'll have to request it again, and then **handle errors again**. In particular, the image could either be damaged somehow (but the headers still correct), or it could have been deleted in the meantime. Since HTTP does not provide any transaction mechanism, you still need to handle errors in `imagecreatefromjpeg`.

Comment: The criticism to `@` is fair. However, the sped of the call does not matter, *any* php code will be **dwarfed** by the actual image processing, let alone network communication: Even fast network communication is in the range of tenth of milliseconds. The overhead of `@` has been measured as .005ms, which is totally irrelevant here. In case of a fatal error (like memory exhaustion, not unlikely when operating with images), catching only the desired error level is indeed better. Updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529084/h/7529116#7529116).

Comment: @Fabio cURL is far out the best option in this case, though I would wrap the function into a class, make the `image_exists` function take another argument, being `$fetch_image` or similar. This would tell the class to fetch the image too during the operation. Store that data in a variable in the class. You can then later retrieve that data from the class (with something like $class -> imagedata) if you're satisfied with the result of the cURL (a return true). This is what I would have ended up answering, but since you're so close :p

Answer (score 1):

If [`imagecreatefromjpeg`](http://php.net/imagecreatefromjpeg) steps over an error (like the file not being readable), it will return false, and, depending on the server configuration, output an error message. Outputting an error message (or *anything*) makes php send the request headers automatically. After headers have been sent, you can't take them back to indicate you're actually sending an image instead of a HTML document.

Therefore, you may want to suppress error output, like this:

```
set_error_handler(function($en, $es) {}, E_WARNING);
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);
restore_error_handler();
if ($im === false) {
   header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
   readfile('static/red-x-icon.jpeg');
   exit();
}
// Continue processing $im, eventually send headers and the image itself
```

Comment: Error supression using `@` is evil

Comment: @JohnD Why? Error suppression using `@` is actually required in this case where an error is expected and correctly handled.

Comment: +1 To remove the unnecessary downvote. Its evil but its a correct answer.

Comment: @Mob In general, I agree that `@` should be avoided when it's used to just suppress errors. However, in this case, there is actual error handling in place, and the error handling is appropriate. Therefore, I don't understand why `@` should be evil here.

Comment: @Nikolai In your case, you need to suppress the errors in `open_image` (or otherwise silence them, for example with output buffering or `set_error_handler`), and then add the content of the `if` around line 49.

Comment: @phihag There is a bounty for 100 reputation

Comment: @mtopia Extended a little bit, but I'm not sure what else to cover, to improve, or to extend.

Comment: @phihag I will find it really helpful if you pasted the code into a the timthumb i posted (through codepad). I tried it in the previous days but didn't do it correctly

Comment: @JohnD : "Error supression using @ is evil". Since when is a programming construct "evil"? Stop regurgitating dogmatic bs and learn how to program.

Comment: @Herbert Because instead of handling the error when it occurrs or in some cases working to prevent it, users just use the @ symbol to prevent the error from occurring and go on with their business. It's one of PHP's features that should be avoided. By your logic, we should also still be using magic quotes, right?

Comment: @JohnD: "magic quotes". I can see your point about that. You're right that _some_ people misuse @, but there are legitimate uses for error suppression. E.g. loading invalid HTML into the DOM for parsing.

Comment: @JohnD Also note that the question already indicates the user does **not** want to do ignore the error (à la `On Error Resume Next`), but explicitly handle the error by showing an error picture. In these cases, `@` is justified. Magic quotes, on the other hand, have no advantage in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Create an error handler using [set_error_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php), and if an error is thrown just return a blank image and possibly log the error elsewhere.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, and will require lots of code to make sure to only handle that exact error you want. Also, this overrides any other error handlers and is a demonstration of using a [global switch to solve a local problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/11/9193695.aspx). If I wouldn't have given an answer in this thread, I'd -1 this.

Comment: It does not make sense to protect against one singular error in this case, as this script is outputting image data, so any invalid data output from the script causes an undersired result (A corrupted image). Better to handle all future cases than just this instance.

Comment: @JohnD will this be in the timthumb.php ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not [see if you can open the image file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) first?

```
function fileExists($path){
    return (@fopen($path,"r")==true);
}

$img = 'no_image.jpg';
if (fileExists(thumb[0])) {
    $img = thumb[0];
}
```

Also, are you checking to make sure you are not passing a non-jpeg (PNG, etc) image to imagecreatefromjpeg()?

Comment: Technically you would be hitting the url twice. Of course you could use fopen to copy the file to your server and then operate on it.

Comment: This is one example of image that timThumb gives an error `http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-NGs14MhxyR4/Tn1upLyA8YI/AAAAAAAAc_Q/zjtRPXFNOL8/s400/%25CE%25A0%25CE%25B1%25CE%25BB%25CE%25AC%25CE%25B4%25CE%25B9%25CE%25BF.gif&h=74&w=150&q=90` Is this because the image is .gif ?

Comment: If you pass a gif to imagecreatefromjpeg() it will return PHP Warning: ... is not a valid JPEG file - so yes, you need to check your mime types and act accordingly.

Comment: But I just checked it with another .gif images and it is working

Comment: Your question states you are getting a 404 error on certain images, using fopen to check on the image first, or using cURL as in @Fabio's answer will solve that part of your problem. Dealing with mime types and how GD deals with non-jpeg images is a little different.

Answer (score 0):

This can be the problem when the page does not allow to download images when user agent is not set. Try to set one before running `imagecreatefromjpeg`. For instance:

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; U; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0');
```